# Symfony2 calling controller function from buildform function

Tags: symfony

**How do I call a custom function in the controller class of my bundle from the buildForm function of the AbstractType class of the same bundle?**

My AbstractType:buildForm function works fine and generates my desired form but I have to add an extra field which will be a dropdown field of selectable options.

I need to dynamically generate the options for the dropdown list from data in the database - which I am already generating in the controller class.

Comment: You could set a private property, pass the items through the constructor of the Form Type and then fetch them within the `buildForm` method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sjagr, I've found a working solution.

Previously I had tried the following:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SalesType(), new Sale(),
   array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('sales_add'),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'arguments' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
    )
)
```

But I hadn't paid enough attention to the resulting error message: **The option "arguments" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields" ...**

I changed the **arguments** index of the array above to **allow_extra_fields** and my array arguments data was then available in the **$options** parameter of the **buildForm** function